# Solving a complex ODE with complex exponents

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, radicals

I have following ODE, with the constraint that $n\neq1$:
$$\bigg(y'\bigg)^{n-1}=ny^{n-1}$$
This is easily solveable in $\mathbb{R}$, however in this case both $y(z)$ and $n$ can be complex.

I would really like to just take the (n-1)th root on both sides. However since taking the root of a complex numbers yields multiple correct answers, I'm worried that I will miss out on solutions for $y(z)$. Is there a correct way to proceed here?

Comment: You would get $y’=\sqrt[n-1]nye^\frac{2\pi i k}{n-1},k\in\Bbb Z$. One would take the multivalued $n-1$th root instead of the square root.

Comment: I misspelled the (n-1)th root for the square root. Thanks for pointing that out, I changed it now.

Comment: Can you elaborate further how you got to this solution?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but n is just a complex parameter in this equation, my y(z) can have n in it but it is dependent from the complex number z or in other words $y(z): \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 2):

$$(y’)^{n-1}=ny^{n-1} \iff\left(\frac{y’}y\right)^{n-1}=n$$

Remember the [complex logarithm](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/05/), $k\in\Bbb Z$:

$$(n-1)\ln\left(\frac{y’}y\right)=\ln(n)+2\pi i k\\\ln\left(\frac{y’}y\right)=\frac{\ln(n)}{n-1}+\frac{2\pi i k}{n-1}\\\frac{y’}y=\sqrt[n-1]n e^{\frac{2\pi i k}n}$$

Now integrate:

$$\int\frac{y’}y dz=\int\sqrt[n-1]n e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n-1}}dz\\\ln(y)= \sqrt[n-1]n e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n-1}}z +C$$

Finally, exponentiate and set $e^C=c$. Therefore:

$$y=ce^{\sqrt[n-1]n e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n-1}}z},k\in\Bbb Z$$

Comment: I thought "$n$" was the complex variable, like the functions were $y(n)$ with $n\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Joako The question says “both $y(z)$ and $n$ can be complex”